# I have created a chat box with submit button but text area losing focus on clicking submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, chat

In my mobile site, i have a chat functionality which basically does have a display area, text area to write and a send button to submit text, the issue is when I write text in text area mobile keypad pops up and when I hit send button it loses focus and submits the text and keypad of mobile disappear my requirement is to that keypad should not disappear on clicking send button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be you are using click() function for send message, for touch devices you can simply use 'touchend' event like as following:

```
$(document).on('touchend', 'selector' ,function(){
    //you code goes here
});
```

now your focus will remain on textarea.
Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

You could overwrite the `onsubmit` function of your `<form>` element.
By default, the form deletes the content of all `<input>`s and sends the content to whatever is specified in your `action` attribute.
If you want to overwrite this behavior, just call the `preventDefault` method on the `submit` event. Sample:

```js
var form = document.getElementById('my-form');
var input = document.getElementById('my-input');

form.onsubmit = function (event) {
  // Prevent the form from sending the content
  // and deleting it afterwards
  event.preventDefault();
  
  // Focus the input element again
  input.focus();
  
  // Send the content via ajax to your endpoint
  alert('sending content...');
}
```

```html
<form id="my-form" action="/message" method="POST">
  <input type="text" id="my-input" />
  <input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

focus the input text area so that you will get focused on the text area and keypad appears on the scree.

use input.focus() in java script function using which you submitted the data. if you directly submitted data then change the code and in after the ajax request and response completed focus the textbox again